# High-performance big data manipulation in R

Tags: performance, r, dataframe, bigdata, reshape2

I am dealing with a collection of lists, which contain deeply nested lists with no fixed structure other than the fact that:

1. The lists at level 1 have a single element called `variations`
2. All leaf data in the hierarchy is numeric.

For example:

```
list(
  list(variations = list(
    '12'   = list(x = c(a = 1))
    )),
  list(variations = list(
    '3'    = list(x = c(a = 6, b = 4)),
    'abcd' = list(x = c(b = 1), m = list(n = list(o = c(p = 1023))))
    ))
  )
```

I need to convert the list data structure into a melted (per `reshape`) dataframe of the form

```
data.frame(
  variation = c( '12',   '3',   '3', 'abcd',    'abcd'),
  variable  = c('x.a', 'x.a', 'x.b',  'x.b', 'm.n.o.p'),
  value     = c(    1,     6,     4,      1,      1023)
  )
```

or another data structure I can perform fast grouping and filtering on.

There are many millions of nodes in the data structure. The collection can have thousands of entries and each entry has tens of thousands of variations with 2-10+ leaf nodes with unknown names.

I am looking for suggestions on how to build the dataframe from the collection in a fast way.

One approach would be to use `unlist` on the source data to flatten the lists but I am not sure about the following:

- Should I run `unlist` on the whole data structure, which will convert the leaf numeric nodes to strings (which I will then need to parse back into numerics) or should I use `unlist` on each variation (which will leave the numeric leaf nodes intact)?
- What's a good way to parse the long names that `unlist` will create to extract `variation` and `variable` values without generating too many intermediate values?

Regardless of whether `unlist` is the right way to go, I'm wondering:

- Is it better to built separate `variation`, `variable` and `value` vectors or a matrix and then combine them into a dataframe as opposed to build the dataframe row-by-row?
- Should I not be using dataframes but another, faster, data structure for dealing with this type of data? Whatever I end up using needs to be convertible to dataframes for use with `plyr`, `reshape` and `ggplot`.

Comment: Where does your data come from? If it is coming from outside R, and you either have to run this conversion many times, or you truly have +10M nodes, I'd write it in C and produce a compressed save.image() file. And load that into R with the types, and layout specified such that it is easy for plyr and others to do their job. If it is a one-off job, I'd just do it in R and have a long coffee break.

Comment: How long it takes to process your data using unlist?

Comment: @user1666959 The data comes from MongoDB. I'd need to do this frequently and, yes, I plan on persisting locally.

Comment: @WojciechSobala I have not implemented the straight unlist version yet: wanted to get some expert advice on approach first.

Answer (score 3):

There's a function that doesn't seem to get used much called `rapply` which recursively operates on lists.  I have no idea how fast it is (based on `lapply`, so probably not terrible but not amazing), and it's tricky to use.  But worth considering, if only for elegance.

Here's one basic example of its use:

```
> rapply( test, classes="numeric", how="unlist", f=function(var) data.frame(names(var),var) )
      variations.12.x.names.var.              variations.12.x.var       variations.3.x.names.var.1       variations.3.x.names.var.2              variations.3.x.var1 
                             "a"                              "1"                              "a"                              "b"                              "6" 
             variations.3.x.var2     variations.abcd.x.names.var.            variations.abcd.x.var variations.abcd.m.n.o.names.var.        variations.abcd.m.n.o.var 
                             "4"                              "b"                              "1"                              "p"                           "1023"
```

Comment: Thanks, Ari, I will play with this.

Comment: Ari, I don't think `rapply` will help as it wants to treat all lists in the data structure identically. In this case, lists at various places in the hierarchy should be treated differently.

Comment: @Sim Can you write that logic into the function you pass to `rapply`?  Maybe flag them with different attributes beforehand?

Comment: Interesting idea, Ari but there are hundreds of thousands of different data structure variations.